# Why is archive.php used for my page

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I have a page "Portfolio", it contains a loop that outputs the list of portfolio (Custom Post Type, *is this the problem?*) items using `page-portfolio.php`. Problem is somehow WordPress used the `archive.php` to render my portfolio page, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An archive of a custom post type is displayed using `archive-[posttype].php` or `archive.php` if the first does not exist (see [the Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for the full details). `page-[posttype].php` is only used if you create a "dummy" page to show a custom post type archive (before WordPress 3.1).

So in your case you should rename `page-portfolio.php` to `archive-portfolio.php`, and don't include a header to indicate a page template name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use portfolio.php for the Custom Post Type "Portfolio".

The way I have solved it on a site I did recently was to call my Custom Post Type "Project" instead. Then pull the content in via a Page Template called portfolio.php (see Brady's answer).
Then to show the single Projects, I use a template called single-project.php

Comment: Was this before [custom post type archives were introduced in WordPress 3.1](http://mark.mcwilliams.me/2010/10/wordpress-3-1-introduces-custom-post-type-archives/)?

Comment: Well Jan, I am not really sure as I have it working this way on 3.0, 3.1 and 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the comment block to your `page-portfolio.php` to tell its a template.

Add this to the top of the file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: A Template Name of Your Choice
*/
?>
```

Go into pages in the admin area of WordPress and create a page and assign the above template to that page.